# Can't import LoginManager() in Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am using Flask BluePrint in my applications and have to main parts: 1. Admin and 2. Public. When I try to import the loginManager to my views.py file I get the error **ImportError: cannot import name lm** 
my folder structure is like:

```
~/LargeApplication
    |-- run.py
    |-- config.py
    |__ /env             # Virtual Environment
    |__ /app             # Application Module
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- models.py
         |-- /admin
             |-- __init__.py
             |-- views.py                
         |__ /templates
             |-- ..
    |__ ..
    |__ .
```

I do initialize the LoginManager() in __ init__ .py file
/app/__ init__ .py

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'
```

and when I try to import **lm** in /app/admin/views.py

```
from app import lm
```

it raises ImportError.

```
ImportError: cannot import name lm
```

Can you please tell what might be the issue?

Comment: Where is `app.admin.views` imported? You need to make sure this happens *after* the `lm = LoginManager()` line has executed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably have a circular import. This is fine, but you need to take into account that you'll be working with modules that haven't yet completed all top-level instructions.

If you have code like:

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from app.admin import admin_blueprint

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'
```

then `app.admin` will be imported *before* the `lm = LoginManager()` line has executed; any code in `app.admin` that then tries to address `app.lm` will fail.

Move blueprint imports down your module and `lm` will have been created already:

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'

from app.admin import admin_blueprint
```

See the [Circular Imports note](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/) in the 'Larger Applications' documentation section of the Flask manual.

Comment: Great answer. That helped.